# Project/Task Management Software quest

Tags: project-management

Are there any cloud-based project management software products that have all of the following features:

- configurable dashboards
- global workspace/project/task view
- unlimited collaborators
- built-in or tightly integrated calendar, email and Gantt charts with dependencies
- draggable tasks, @mentions, notifications, recurring events, user-defined project templates and reports
- mobile app (iOS & Android), desktop client (OSX and Windows), and an integration API?

Of the 20+ PM tools we've trialled so far, the best fit to our requirements we've found is Flow, but it lacks unlimited collaborators and Gantt capabilities. Wrike and asana also come close but both lack a global task view. Wrike also lacks a desktop client and draggable tasks.